# Need brew to overwrite /usr/local/etc/httpd/

Tags: macos, apache, homebrew, httpd.conf

I am struggling to get a clean reinstall of httpd.

I modified the ServerRoot instead of the DocumentRoot and don't recall the original value.

No combination of `brew uninstall httpd` / `brew reinstall --force httpd` is actually removing the files in the /usr/local directories. Or overwriting them with the default's from a fresh install.

I am not sure if I should delete them myself.

But Basically what I am trying to do is to completely fresh install httpd.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I did these steps, and one or their combination fixed the issue.

```
cd /usr/local/etc/httpd
mkdir ~/httpd
mv * ~/httpd
brew install -s -f -v  httpd

RBAINDOU-M-4116:httpd robert$ cat httpd.conf | grep -i root
# with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so "logs/access_log"
# with ServerRoot set to "/usr/local/apache2" will be interpreted by the
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# ServerRoot at a non-local disk, be sure to specify a local disk on the
# same ServerRoot for multiple httpd daemons, you will need to change at
ServerRoot "/usr/local/opt/httpd"
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/var/www"
    # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
RBAINDOU-M-4116:httpd robert$
```